# PowerPoint VBA "Out of Memory"

Tags: vba, out-of-memory, powerpoint

This is my first foray in to using VBA in PowerPoint, so I'm hoping it's just bad code design and can be fixed easily.

Each month I produce a presentation that is basically a table of values with 3 columns, which represent the last 3 months. When I come to update this for the next month, I want the middle column to become the left column, and the right column to become the middle column. The right column will then get new data.

At the moment all I am trying to do is "move" text across the columns as described. Like so:

```
Sub MoveData()

    Dim Infra1Array(270, 267, 211, 213, 50, 51, 145, 185) As Integer

    For i = 1 To UBound(Infr1Array)
        ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes("" & Infr1Array(i) & "_1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes("" & Infr1Array(i) & "_2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes("" & Infr1Array(i) & "_2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes("" & Infr1Array(i) & "_3").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    Next i
End Sub
```

You can see the "rows" if you like, in my array. Then each row has 3 textboxes, the shapes are then the row number with _1, _2, and _3.

However, when I run this loop I get "out of memory". Am I doing something wrong or am I expecting too much from PowerPoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the multi-dimensional array you create with:

```
Dim Infra1Array(270, 267, 211, 213, 50, 51, 145, 185) As Integer
```

this ends up in 270 x 267 x 211 x 213 x 50 x 51 x 145 x 185 Integer vars ... which is really much :) > 200,000,000,000,000,000 and a little bit more as your system memory can handle

I guess what you wanted to have an array containing these 8 values. In this case:

```
Dim Infra1Array(7) As Integer
Infra1Array(0) = 270
Infra1Array(1) = 267
.
.
.
Infra1Array(7) = 185
```

when you use the array only for building new strings, then you can also use a String array and the Split() function.

Overall:

```
Sub MoveData()
    Dim Infra1Array() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Infra1Array = Split("270, 267, 211, 213, 50, 51, 145, 185")

    For i = LBound(Infra1Array) To UBound(Infra1Array)
        ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes("" & Infra1Array(i) & "_1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes("" & Infra1Array(i) & "_2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes("" & Infra1Array(i) & "_2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes("" & Infra1Array(i) & "_3").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh haha, brilliant! You might be right there... I'll do it the long way as you've suggested. I'll leave this up in case anyone else hits the same thing.

Comment: in case you can also live with an array of String values you can make your live a little bit easier by using the Split() function. From your code above I see only that you use that values for joining in another string .... so this would be maybe enough

Comment: It's just arrays of integers at the moment to repeat the same code for a group of numbers. I'm now struggling to get the loop to run, type mismatch. I think my array still isn't set up properly so I'll keep working.

Comment: yeah ... the loop has another problem. Arrays by default start with position 0 and not with 1. But this depends also a little bit on the system settings. Best way is to use UBound like you alrady have and instead of 1 LBound for the lower boundary of the array ... so: For i = LBound(Infr1Array) To UBound(Infr1Array)

Comment: And again BTW: you should always declare all vars ... also i. Therefore it helps to put on top of each VBA module: Option Explicit

Comment: there is also another typo in your code. Sometimes you name the array Infra1Array and then only Infr1Array. This is again something Option Explicit would avoid. I have adjusted the code and pasted in the answer above

Comment: I eventually noticed this, after it kept saying "variable not declared" so the option explicit definitely helped. Thank you! It works as expected now.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `Dim infArray() As Variant` and then `InfArray = Array(270, 267, 211, 213, 50, 51, 145, 185)`

Comment: Yep - always use LBound and UBound because if some bright spark comes along and adds/changes the global Option Base statement somewhere in your project to change the lower bound index of arrays, you're in for a REALLY bad day.